# Why is my returned DataSet instance has no tables?

Tags: c#, database, ado.net

When I connect to the DB and I want to read data from table it doesn't work an shows these
Exception Details:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
>   Error in Line 141

I have only one table in the dataset. Do you know the best way to read from table for me ? I return only one table. When I use foreach, how can I read a one row data?

```
       internal DataSet read(string query)
        {
        DataSet nds = new DataSet();
        try
        {

            string connectionString = "...";
            try
            {

                SqlConnection nsqlc = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand(query, nsqlc);
                nsqlc.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter nsda = new SqlDataAdapter(get);
                nsda.Fill(nds);
                nsqlc.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {


            }

            return nds;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return nds;
        }
    }
```

Main form :

```
            links = links + t.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "%";

           String links = "";
            links = "movie%";
            DataSet t = n.read("select id , poster from Movie order by id desc");
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                links = links + t.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "%";
                links = links + t.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + "%";

            }
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `n.read()` is and does...

Comment: Have you considered plugging that into a debugger (yeah, I know, noone uses them) and checking why this variable is null, possibly y stepping through the code? THis is stuff you should learn at he beginning - using tools and basic debugging.

Comment: Yeah. Need to show the code for `n.read`. Its clearly not adding the table to the dataset as you think it is...

Comment: Don't try to quietly return your `DataSet` when catching an Exception. Exceptions are things to be handled, not things you try to pave over. I'm thinking there's a helpful message you're burying there. If so, could you show that to us?

Comment: fwiw: your `read(string query)` method is forcing you to write horribly unsafe code that _will_ be vulnerable to sql injection attacks and _will_ eventually result in your app getting hacked.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is this 'n' prefix you put into every variable? I would advise you to properly name variables to what they are, without using these abbreviations. On Topic: this question shows that you should have researched at least a little bit and tried stuff before asking.

Comment: That first-level `try/catch` block is actually pretty strange. Why do you even do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>The closest thing to an answer here would have to be that the `n.read` method returns a `DataSet` instance that has no tables in it. You need to step into the method with a debugger and figure out why it behaves like that.</s>

If you see what the problem is, fix it. If not, share the `read` method code and someone will be able to help you further.

Looking at your updated post, I see that you are swallowing every possible exceptions that could occur while trying to fetch data. Remove the `catch` block from your `read` method. This will allow you to see what the *real* problem is.

Exception swallowing is something you'll want to take away from your code on a global scale. I'd suggest that you do some Googling to find out why it's a terrible habit.

About a "better way to read from table", you should consider using a `IDataReader`.

```
string links = "movie%";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
{
    using (var command = someExistingConnection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select id, poster from Movie order by id desc";
        command.Connection = connection;

        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var idValue = reader.GetObject(0).ToString(); // would be better to use actual field type, which is unknown at the time I'm writing this
                    var posterValue = reader.GetString(1);

                    // perform concatenation here using the two variables declared above
                    links += String.Format("{0}%{1}%", idValue, posterValue);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This will outperform working with a `DataSet` by a long shot.

Comment: thanks... when i delet the catch i find the problom. i cant connected to db. you know what the problem in my connetion string :connectionString = "Server=.;Database=irt;User Id=irt;Password=124;" + "Integrated Security=true;";

Comment: I can't possibly know what could be the problem about your connection string, because 1) you are not showing it and 2) even if you did there would be no way for me to properly diagnose a connection problem with that little information. Unless there would be some very obvious flaws on how it's built (missing actual server name for instance :p ).

Comment: my code uploded in host and i want to connect to the host db .. !! :(

Comment: As I said there's hardly anything I can do about that without having more details. Besides, if you are having problems with connecting to your database, I think you should post another question about that specific problem.